# Open read-only, shared OneNote (via OneDrive) in desktop OneNote

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I am hosting a rather large OneNote notebook with frequent changes on my OneDrive where a public read-only link is shared.

Is it possible for other users to access it offline and/or save this notebook as PDF using their desktop/full OneNote application?

Answer (score 1):

- This solution is borrowed from the following link

[Downloading a local copy of One Note from Office 365 Online](https://superuser.com/questions/1213813/downloading-a-local-copy-of-one-note-from-office-365-online)

Onenote online provides an option to export onenote notebooks, but it is well hidden for some weird reason.

This answer is based on one of Microsoft's support articles: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-and-import-onenote-notebooks-a4b60da5-8f33-464e-b1ba-b95ce540f309?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.

Go to https://www.onenote.com/notebooks and sign in with your Microsoft credentials.

You will see your notebooks.

Right click the one you want to export.

There is an option Export notebook. Click that.

A popup window appears and you can click export to download locally (it also lets you choose where to save it).

Hope this helps, although I'm a little late.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access and download all OneDrive items to your local computer. There's two way to do this:

First:

1. Right click on OneDrive icon, and click on “Make available offline.” This will start downloading files to your PC. You can also browse and select files of your choice. At anytime you can right click on OneDrive icon and click on "Make available online-only” to go back to cloud storage.

Second:

1. Open One Drive app, and then open the Charms Bar.
2. Click Settings, then Options.
3. You will see the option Access all my OneDrive files offline, turn the slider “On.” and it will start downloading files.

Alternate Method:

1. Find out if a file is available for offline or not. Just click on any file and wondows status bar will let you know. See the pic.

[image]

2. Now right click on the file and click “Make available offline.”
3. Now right click on the OneDrive icon in the taskbar and click settings and check the box saying "Make all files available even when this PC isn't connected to the Internet".

[image]

The above method for Windows 8.1.

The original [article](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/onedrive-offline-files).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but that does not solve my problem. I as the owner can download and access the notebook offline anyway, but other users who just have the link pointing to my shared notebook can't and it does not even show up in their OneDrive as it is a public link...